# how do I get all of the source files of a website?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is to make a server that gets the website page and send it to the client from a recognized domain.

The server itself is already done. All I need right now is to get all of the source files of a website like when I **right-click on the webpage and then "save as.."** the page, so the HTML file and all the images, **JS and PHP** (edit: by PHP I **don't mean** to the **source PHP files** of server, but to the files that are created when I do this procedure) files are also saved in a folder alongside the HTML file.

I used **wget** to get the HTML but how do i use it to get everything else?
(I also tried using Beatiful Soup)

```
def store_links(page):
    fh = open(page + ".html", "wb")
    site = urllib.urlopen(page)
    site_data = site.read()
    fh.write(site_data)
    wget.download(page)
```

As someone mentioned here, maybe phasing the HTML file then get all of the files (images for instance) **url** in the **href** segments and then download them to the server.

Comment: you would have to have python load the page enough to recognize what resources it would need to grab as well as possibly changing the links so that it will work in what ever file system you plan on putting it in.  In other words, I wish I knew how.

Comment: You can probably fetch the JS, CSS and all other static content, but I don't really thing you can get **Php** files. That is server side code.

Comment: You absolutely cannot download the PHP files. This is server-side code, and it is not exposed to clients. Also, your question is too broad--try to solve this yourself, post example code, and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: You probably want to use a scaping framework such as http://scrapy.org/
By *PHP-Files* the OP is probably referring to their parsed representation (i.e. the HTML) and not the source.

Comment: Not "phasing" the `html` please, it has not done bad ;) "Parsing" means to analyze the bunch of characters that form the html source of the web page regarding its meaning. `BeautifulSoup` takes this job and offers a simple interface: `soup.img` for example gives the an iterator that will loop over all images in the page. For each `img` of those, you can ask `img["src"]` to get the (relative) URL of to the image. Similar approach for `link` and `href etc. This leaves your task tedious, but makes it managable.

Comment: @flaschbier Your answer helped me a lot. So far I managed to download all images files using `soup.findAll('img')` and I think I understand how to go on from here. BTW, I did meant parsing at the start but apparently I got some auto-correct issues.

Comment: @DvirYamin Great :) Feel free to accept the answer in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have appreciated had you shown us what you have tried so far. Without that information, I can only offer unspecific hints how to proceed.

What you are searching for is very much like a so-called spider: A program that is parsing web pages and following all the links therein, usually customized to respect a certain depth to not accidentally copying the whole internet.

Basically it can be implemented by using a package like `requests` or `curl` to download the page in question from the web and then parse the `html` code for `href=`, `src=` etc. attributes. Except for that, it's only taking care to download binary files as binary and interpret text files with the right `encoding`.

There are some caveats, however:

- What you see in a browser, and what that browser prints, ist *after* processing backend code (e.g. the `PHP` that was mentioned in the comments already) and frontend `JavaScript`, possibly including severe `DOM` manipulation and `ajax` calls. So you should carefully investigate the page you see via "show source code" or so and compare it with what you download via `wget` or the `curl` command line tool.
- When what you see is not what you `wget` and the most interesting information is missing in the `HTML`, you can use a so-called *headless browser* which is actually a full blown browser with a `JavaScript` engine that can build the `DOM` like a browser and pass it to your routines.
- When you parse the `html` you shall safely stay away from using `regex`. Refer to `XML` and `HTML` parsing framewoks such as `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Sorry for being uninformative. I'm kind of a newbe in StackOverflow. I'll edit my post as soon as I can. btw, I tried using BeautifulSoup but I don't know how to use it efficiently.

Comment: @DvirYamin `BeautifulSoup` docs would deserve a bit of attention, indeed. There are, however, some blog entries with good starter examples that can be transferred to your case right away. Maybe this here will be helpful as a starter: http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup Hope this helps.